# How to mask the resourceId field in the REST response of catalog service?

Tags: service, catalog, wcs

The resource id in the REST service response for WCS Catalog service exposes the server url. Is there a way to mask this ?

Answer (score 1):

On your handler class write a method postProcess (responseMap), responseMap contains the result in key value pair. Search for resourceId and remove it from resourceMap.